# android sqlite next record incorrect

Tags: android, sqlite

This is the getContact method which takes the rowID in this case the counter

```
public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                        question, possibleAnsOne,possibleAnsTwo, possibleAnsThree,realQuestion,userR}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            // moves to the the first record
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
```

Here is my problem. I start at record one. So the counter is set to one.

in the public oncreate method. When I click next for some reason it is not setting the value of the first record with db.updateUserResult(counter,8); I think it is missing the first record. The reason I know this is that if I chose the answer which is one ahead. Lets say that Question 1 right answer is option 2 and Question 2's right answer is option 3. If you choose option 3 for question 1 then you get the right answer. If i keep choosing the right answer one record ahead I get all the right results.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
            boolean TimerStarted = b.getBoolean("timerlogic");
            System.out.println("what is the logic of the timer" + TimerStarted);
            Log.e(LOGS, "Whatis the first value for the timer inside the timer_btn" + TimerStarted);

            setContentView(R.layout.basic);
            // this method is better then a try and catch block as it actually prevents the occurence occuring instead of just patching it.
            // the purpose of t
            db.open();

            Cursor c = db.getContact(1); 

            if(c.isFirst())
            {
                TextView question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
                RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
                RadioButton radio2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
                RadioButton radio3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);





                answerCounterText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerCounterText);
                answerCounterText.setText(String.valueOf("0")); 
                // for the first record set the counter to zero
                // question.setText(String.valueOf("0"));
                TextView QuestionNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.QuestionNumber);
                Complete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Continue);
                Complete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.complete);
                Complete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                QuestionNumber.setText(String.valueOf("Question Number  :" + counter));

                  System.out.println("what is the setup counter after loop" + counter);




                //DisplayContact(c,radio1);
                DisplayRadioButton(c,radio1,radio2,radio3,question);

            }


          // }
          //  }
         // Previous = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Previous);
           Next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next);

           Next.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.next);
           // get the results from the checked box


           Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Cursor c = db.getContact(1);

                /*
                if (firstrecordchosen)
                {
                    Cursor c = db.getContact(1);
                      System.out.println("what is the current value of the counter 0" + counter);
                    firstrecordchosen = false;
                }
                counter++;

                  */   
                counter++;
                 Cursor c = db.getContact(counter);

                    if (c.moveToFirst() && !c.isNull(0))        
                    {    
                         TextView question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
                        RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
                         RadioButton radio2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
                         RadioButton radio3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);



                      TextView answerCounterText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerCounterText);
                         TextView QuestionNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.QuestionNumber);
                         RadioGroup radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

                         QuestionNumber.setText(String.valueOf("Question Number  :" + counter));
                         Log.e(LOGS, "default user set variable " + c.getString(5));
                         Log.e(LOGS, "real value" + c.getString(6));
                         System.out.println("what is the current value of the counter" + counter);




                    //  DisplayContact(c,radio1);
                   DisplayRadioButton(c,radio1,radio2,radio3,question);
                  final String questionOneDb = c.getString(5);
                  String radioOneIndex = "1";
                  String radioTwoIndex = "2";
                  String radioThreeIndex = "3";



                  // set the first question to have the right value

                  if(radio1.isChecked() )
                    {     
                        db.updateUserResult(counter,8);
                        if (questionOneDb.equals(radioOneIndex))
                        {

                            Log.e(LOGS, "correct" );    


                        rightAnswer(c,radio1,answerCounterText);
                        //  DisplayContact(c,radio1);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            Log.e(LOGS, "wrong" );  
                        }


                    }




                    if(radio2.isChecked()  )
                    {

                        db.updateUserResult(counter,9);

                        if (questionOneDb.equals(radioTwoIndex))
                        {
                          System.out.println("is this counter being reached"); 
                        //  db.updateUserResult(1, 2);
                        //  db.updateUserResult(counter, 2);
                        // db.updateUserResult(recordval, 6);

                            Log.e(LOGS, "correct" );    


                        rightAnswer(c,radio1,answerCounterText);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e(LOGS, "wrong" );      
                        }

                    }



                    if(radio3.isChecked()   )
                    { 
                        db.updateUserResult(counter,10);

                        if (questionOneDb.equals(radioThreeIndex))
                        {
                            Log.e(LOGS, "correct" );    
                        System.out.println("you have the right answer");
                        rightAnswer(c,radio1,answerCounterText);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e(LOGS, "wrong" );      
                        }


                    }








                    }



                  /* when you get ot the last record you want to be able to close the db */
                    if (c.isAfterLast())

                    { 

                    // this halts the timer when there are no questiosn left
                   Next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               //    Previous.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "More questions available in the full version PHPExpert " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   Complete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    handler.removeCallbacks(timedTask);
                    db.close();

                  intentcalls();


                    }






            }
        });

           Home = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_btn);
           Home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i = new Intent(Basic_database_questionsActivity.this,AndroidGUIActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);


            }


           }); 



        }
```

Comment: Still don't get your problem. You say you have one: `Here is my problem. I start at record one. So the counter is set to one.` but you don't say _what_ your problem is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not totally wrong, you have a timing issue.

First you get your first question and you show the UI (your radio buttons and stuff).

You check with the click on the Next button, if the chosen answer is right, correct?

If so, you make the mistake that you first increase the counter and then query for the question based on counter (which will be the next). After that you check if the chosen radio button is the correct one. As you already read the next question from the database, you check the chosen answer to your first question with the stored answer of the second one.

Hope that was clear.

Short tip: try to clean up some code. Don't put anything inside the `onCreate()` make smaller chunks so you can see and follow the code flow easier...

Comment: I tried making the change ie I moved the counter++; underneath the cursor  Cursor c = db.getContact(counter); I now have the problem where the first record is diplayed when next is clicked. Did I mis understand your answer.

Comment: I am still struggling with your code but basically you should just move the complete `if(radio1.isChecked() )` code (and for the other two radios, too) at the very first of your `onClick()`. That should evaluate the answer and after that you fetch the new question

Comment: Changing the subject of a question is not welcome! You should have created another question. I will revert your question back to the old one. And you should use a debugger and step through your code to understand why what happens...

Comment: could we move this to the discussion I have rewritten my code completely. I mean there is like 10 lines in the public OnCreate method now

Comment: I answered your question, you said you would create a new question since your code changed quite a bit and the problem was a different one. Removing the accepted tick just to get "further information" is definitively impolite. I even checked yesterday if you have yet created the new question...

Comment: I tried to create a new question but it got marked down. I wrote a link to this question but maybe that is why I got marked down. I will give you a tick and rewrite the question today. I will explain in detail the problem and how I am trying to overcome it

Comment: You will probably not get marked down when the question provides enough information. I will come back and see in your profile when you have created the question.

Comment: i will just solve it myself I got marked down for asking a cursorOutofBounds exceptions. I though the whole idea of a site likes this was to learn from others feedback

Comment: I never saw your question. How about not deleting it right away just because you get some down votes?

Comment: Some down votes will not get you banned. You need to post some serious bad questions to get banned.

Comment: one question how do I get upvotes. I provide the problem I am trying to fix a logcat and where I think the problem is. And the code.

Comment: ask the question and I can take a look. I check your profile on a regular base but I don't see the new created question...

Comment: can you send me an email and I will reply with the question

Comment: I think you got banned for multiple deleting your question. And no I will not support via email. Sorry. Try again when your ban is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Cursor c1 = mDbHelper.fetAll(); \\ or whatever your method is to get data from database.
if(c1.moveToFirst()){
     do{
        \\ Do what you want to do with it.

       }while(c1.moveToNext()); \\ this will move the cursor to next line.
    }
 c1.close(); \\ make sure you close it, else errors will pop up in LOGCAT.
```